# Why does make_unique to vector::back() create another copy?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Reproduce a simple example here to demonstrate my question

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

struct Party {
    Party(std::string value) : value_(value) {};
    std::string value_;
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Party>> map_;
    std::vector<Party> parties_;

    parties_.emplace_back("AAA");
    parties_.emplace_back("BBB");
    parties_.emplace_back("CCC");

    std::unique_ptr<Party> ptr = std::make_unique<Party>(parties_.back());

    ptr->value_ = "XXX";

    for (auto& p : parties_) {
        std::cout << p.value_ << std::endl; // print: AAA\nBBB\nCCC
    }

}
```

Essentially, I want to store objects in a vector and have smart pointers pointing to them and to use these pointers to modify the value of the vector's objects.

But it seems like in making a new `unique_ptr`, `parties_.back()` actually return a copy of the object instead of the original object.

How do I achieve what I want here? Thank you!

Comment: The "make" in `make_unique` means creation ("make me a pizza"), not transformation ("make me a millionaire").

Comment: Why do you want a pointer, smart or otherwise, to what is already a reference?

Comment: I think you should just use a reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::make_unique<Party>(something)` is essentially equivalent to `std::unique_ptr<Party>(new Party(something))`, so yes, it is creating new copies of `Party` objects because you asked for it.

Ultimately here `unique_ptr` doesn't seem the right choice: if your `std::vector` is already the sole owner (and manager of lifetime) of the objects, then you don't need to do anything particular, you can just use plain pointers/references. Be advised however that their validity is tied to the references invalidation rules of `std::vector` - in particular, if it decides to reallocate (which can happen e.g. if you do a `push_back`) all pointers/references become invalid.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Party*> map_;
std::vector<Party> parties_;

parties_.emplace_back("AAA");
parties_.emplace_back("BBB");
parties_.emplace_back("CCC");

Party *ptr = &parties_.back();

// Notice: if you do parties_.emplace_back("DDD") here
// ptr may become invalid

ptr->value_ = "XXX";

for (auto& p : parties_) {
    std::cout << p.value_ << std::endl; // print: AAA\nBBB\nXXX
}
```

---

If you want to be isolated from the effects of reallocation, but are ok with `std::vector` being the owner, and thus dictating the lifetime, of your objects, you can have an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Party>>` (and, again, keep plain pointers/references to them around)

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Party*> map_;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Party>> parties_;

parties_.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Party>("AAA"));
parties_.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Party>("BBB"));
parties_.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Party>("CCC"));

Party *ptr = parties_.back().get();

// Notice: if you do parties_.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Party>("DDD"));
// ptr will remain valid

ptr->value_ = "XXX";

for (auto& p : parties_) {
    std::cout << p.value_ << std::endl; // print: AAA\nBBB\nXXX
}
```

This makes sure that objects are allocated independently from the vector, but if they are removed from the vector they'll be deleted.

---

OTOH, if you want shared ownership between the vector and the map, you may want `std::shared_ptr` (which however doesn't come for free, it has to manage reference counting & co.):

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Party>> map_;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Party>> parties_;

parties_.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Party>("AAA"));
parties_.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Party>("BBB"));
parties_.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Party>("CCC"));

std::shared_ptr<Party> ptr = parties_.back();

// Notice: if you do parties_.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Party>("DDD"));
// ptr will remain valid, but it will still be valid even after
// parties_.pop_back() (ptr will keep the pointed object alive)

ptr->value_ = "XXX";

for (auto& p : parties_) {
    std::cout << p.value_ << std::endl; // print: AAA\nBBB\nXXX
}
```

This makes sure that the objects' lifetime is not tied to the lifetime of the vector, as any copy of the original `std::shared_ptr` will (1) point to the same object and (2) keep it alive.

Comment: All answers explain the root cause and provide a fix but I ultimately choose this since if offers multiple alternatives that can be useful for someone else who stumbles upon this and have a slightly different problem.

Comment: @resnet thank you! Yep, that was exactly the idea when writing this, especially as in the original question it wasn't completely clear what ownership model was called for (and that's _fine_, it's not always obvious!), I tried to provide the most common alternatives for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

`std::make_unique<Party>(parties_.back())` creates a *new* object, always. It's a wrapper for `std::unique_ptr<Party>(new Party(parties_.back()))`. Note that `parties_.back()` itself is not copying anything, it returns a reference.

In your code `ptr` does not need to own the `Party` its points to: `parties_` is already the owner. Just use a reference or a raw pointer:

```
Party &lastParty = parties_.back();
lastParty.value_ = "XXX";
```

Answer (score 2):

These two objects

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Party>> map_;
std::vector<Party> parties_;
```

both own the `Party` instances, as a `std::vector` always owns its elements, and `std::unique_ptr` is intended for exclusively owning the pointee. You need to decide which container is supposed to own the parties and manage their lifetimes. Example: `std::vector<Party>` owns the instances, then you can go with ordinary pointers.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Party*> map_;
std::vector<Party> parties_;
```

Plain pointers are ok to go with when they don't involve ownership semantics. Once you made this decision, the original question w.r.t. `parties_.back()` and `std::make_unique` (which *always* creates a new instance due to the purpose of `std::unique_ptr`) is no longer an issue.